# Project has many errors related to Spring data JPA, and these errors won't go at all

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, dependencies

I have a lot of errors in my project and they won't go off and I know that they are related to Dependency related stuff but I'm confused. Can someone tell me how to fix this if you have also faced the same kind of issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this one in your XML:

We use JPA namespace for XML based enabling like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    https://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd">

  <jpa:repositories base-package="path.to.repository.package" />

</beans>
```